# using resource files in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a folder in asp.net 4.0 application with local resource files for different cultures. These resource files have name/value pairs. I want to use these name/value pairs in asp.net page. how can i use it.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.GetLocalResourceObject("Resourcename").ToString();
```

Comment: and how to access the specific key in resource file

Comment: These resource files are located in another project but in same solution. There are 15 resource files for 15 different cultures. I want to access them in different web project in same solution. do I need to use global resources syntax or what because local resource method is returning null.

Comment: your both projects are web project

Comment: The one which has resource files is class library where as the one using resources is web project

Comment: resource file is global or local??? if global den use this syntax this.GetLocalResourceObject